# Ruby on Rails font files not found

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-4, virtualhost, glyphicons, bootstrap-sass

I'm using bootstrap icons on Ruby on Rails with bootstrap-sass.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
```

It works fine locally. However, my production server use apache virtual host to redirect the url, which means my url changed from localhost:3000 to www.foo.com/bar/.

Everything else works fine (stylesheet, images), except when I use bootstrap icons, the browser tried to download fronts (.eot, .woff, .ttf) from

> www.foo.com/assets

instead of

> www.foo.com/bar/assets

Is there anyway to fix this?

Below are the gem I use

> gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
>
> gem 'sass-rails'
>
> gem 'sprockets-rails'
>
> gem 'bootstrap-sass'

my application.css

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

and scaffolds.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/theme";
```

Answer (score -1):

application.css needs to be application.css

and the the

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";